# circular saw bevel screw

Tags: circular-saw

[image: thin screw]

hi - Please guide what this thin screw is for and how it used. I searched a lot but no luck. Not even in product mannual.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. We're going to need a *much* larger (and in-focus) photo of the screw to give us any idea of what type of screw it is, since "bevel screw" is not a recognised term. But since this screw wasn't included in the product manual it is possible it ended up in the packaging by accident, such things do occur occasionally on production lines.

Comment: Does it bump up against anything solid when you have the blade at 90 degrees to the table? If so, it's an adjustment screw that should reliably get you squared up.

Comment: Stanley SC16? If I understand what you're pointing at, it is a travel stop as detailed below.

Comment: Yes Stanley SC16

Comment: Please [edit] the question and put the model details in the body of the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *very* hard to tell exactly what screw you're talking about from that distant and blurry picture. However there are a couple of possibilities.

- You're talking about the large screw with a large knob. This is used to tighten/loosen the screw that holds the sole plate. Loosening this allows the sole plate to pivot, allowing the saw to cut at an angle other than 90°. There is a scale on the curved piece that will, when adjusted properly, show you what angle you're cutting at.
- There are small screws, 3-5mm in diameter, with a small hex inset near the sole plate tilt mechanism. These are travel stops that are designed to be used once and forgotten about.

  Use a known 90° to get the sole adjusted to exactly 90° from the blade and set the 90° stop.

  Using a known 45° angle to get the sole adjusted to exactly 45° from the blade and set the 45° stop.

  Theoretically, these should never have to be adjusted again, but theory rarely matches up with reality. It's good to check blade angle every now and then, especially before making a critical cut.

---

Funny, five days later and I've just realized that saw says "Stanley" on the label, not DeWalt so the comments below about DeWalt (and the link to their repair site) don't really apply, the 3rd party part suppliers should both carry parts for them, and the recommendation for finding the official Stanley parts supply is the same as that for finding the DeWalt parts site.

---

- If you're talking about the screw in your fingers (which I just saw). I'm not sure what that one's for, but you're right, it's probably *not* in the manual because DeWalt tools *rarely* come with a loose screw that needs to be installed. (I know, I've got a lot of 'em!). I'd suggest using DeWalt's own [service/parts website](https://www.toolservicenet.com/dewalt/en) (which shouldn't take much searching for - go to DeWalt.com, then click on "service" - it'll take you right there), or a third party site like https://www.ereplacementparts.com/ or https://www.partswarehouse.com/ (both places I've shopped at and gotten good prices & service from - no other affiliation).

  Once you've picked a site, enter your tool's model number (generally 3 letters, 3 digits, possibly 1 more letter, though other possibilities exist). It will then ask for a "Type". Both the model & type will be listed on the tool's label. You'll get a parts diagram and parts list - you can search for "bevel screw" (not a term I've heard of, despite having just made repairs to my cordless circular saw) in the parts list, and the numbered drawing will show you *exactly* where the part goes.

Comment: Well bravo, it's hard to provide a good Answer to a poor Q but you've sure managed it!

Comment: Thank you for the kind words! I usually refrain from answering until we get better details, but, unfortunately, further details are often not forthcoming, as evidenced by this question.